# using Wagtail's site settings outside wagtail app

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I have a Django project with a Wagtail app and I would like to use Wagtail Site settings outside Wagtail app but inside the Django project.

The BaseSetting model seems to be well definded, I can setup fields and modify them through the Wagtail admin interface:

```py
@register_setting
class MarketplaceSettings(BaseSetting):
    test =  models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
...
```

**First try**

Following the [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/settings.html), I have tried to load settings template tags:

- within wagtail templates which was working
- within other templates of the project which was not working

**Second try**

I tried to create simple tags and inclusion tags in which I have loaded wagtail's site settings data, so that I could have loaded them in a template which was not holding a wagtail view but it was not working.

**Third try**

I tried to register **get_settings** function from **wagtailsettings_tags.py** module outside wagtail an call it within a template but it was also a fail.

I feel like I am running out of ideas to solve this issue. If someone has a clue it would be great, i am sure there is a smart way to extend wagtail site settings to my entire project.

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working" - any error messages?

Comment: Hello, No error message, the global context processor was empty, I made a couple of cleans on my configs and suddenly it works